# How do I pass a List of values from one DataTemplate to another?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a list of string values (or tags) that I'm wanting to create a DataTemplate within another DataTemplate.  For example, say I have an object with strings, ints and a list of strings.  The list of strings is the set of tags I'm interested in.  For each tag I have a specific DataTemplate I want to use:

```
<!-- This is the Tag Template-->
<DataTemplate x:Name="TagTemplate">
    <Border Background="LightGray">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TagValue}"/> <!-- This is where I'm not sure how to reference the individual tag-->
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

And the main body of the other DataTemplate would contain the tags like this:

```
<!-- This is the main Data Template for the overall data-->
<DataTemplate>
     <Grid>
          <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TagTemplate }"/>
          <!-- Below is a commented static representation of the tags-->
          <!--<TextBlock Text="TAG, TAG, TAG, TAG, TAG" Margin="5, 5, 5, 5"/>-->
     </Grid>
<DataTemplate>
```

The DataBinding for the Tags would be a list of strings `List<String> Tags`

My problem is I'm not exactly sure how to reference the second binding or if even passing a list of anything is possible from one `DataTemplate` to another.  Is this possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Tags collection is `List<String>` then in your `DateTemplate` the `DataContext` will be the actual item: so a given `string` and you can bind to the current `DataContext` with the following syntax:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="TagTemplate">
    <Border Background="LightGray">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```